# C# - Failed to compare two elements in the array

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code:

```
 var distinctDateValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row => new
                   {
                       Date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("DAY"))
                   })
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();

 distinctDateValues.Sort(); // getting error on this line
```

Values in distinctDateValues are:

[image]

The error i am getting is "Failed to compare two elements in the array."

Can anybody suggest me as what i am doing wrong here. I want to sort the values in date column of distinctDateValues.

Comment: Do you really need an enumeration of anonymous objects with only one field (`Date`)? You could simply put the `DateTime` values into your enumeration directly.

Comment: Why not `OrderBy` with the Linq?

Comment: To do a `Sort` on a `List<Something>`, each time you have two elements from the list, the algorithm has to be able to determine which one is greater than the other. This requires that the (one of the two) objects implement `IComparable`, `IComparable<Something>` or similar. You use an anonymous type becasue use say `new { Date = xxx }`. While anonymous types override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, they do not implement `IComparable` or similar. So you can say if two instances of the anonymous type are equal or not, but you can't tell if one is "greater than" the other!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Needless to create anonymous type, in your case the result `distinctDateValues` is a list of *anonymous type*, not a list of `DateTime`, you should get the sorted list of `DateTime` like below with `OrderBy`:

```
var distinctDateValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => row.Field<DateTime>("DAY"))
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(x => x)
               .ToList();
```

Also, you should use built-in method `Field<DateTime>` instead of using one more step with `DateTime.Parse`

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing here... your `distinctDateValues` don't know how to compare themselves... You would need to implement `IComparable` or something...

Try this:

```
var distinctDateValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("DAY")))
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();

 distinctDateValues.Sort(); // should not get any errors here...
```

If you really want to create an anonymous type (e.g., you are only showing us a small part of your code), try this:

```
var distinctDateValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => new
               {
                   Date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("DAY"))
               })    
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(d => d.Date) // do the sorting here with linq
               .ToList();
```